# Cutoff circuit with bipolar transistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-protection, over-discharge

I'm trying to build a cutoff circuit with a PNP bipolar transistor (TIP42C) and a TL431A.

[image]

[image]

R1 = 2.2k
R2 = 11k
R3 = 220
R4 = 4.7k
The circuit should allow the current to flow when the voltage is above the cutoff (set with resistor at about 15V) and then open the circuit when the input voltage reaches the cutoff voltage. The IN and OUT GNDs are connected together while the VCC IN is provided to the base, and VCC OUT is drawn from the collector.

The circuit is working well if the load is not present and I use a multimeter to test the output voltage, but when I apply a load (even a small LED,) the output voltage drops close to 0.

The TL431A voltages are constant with and without load.  They are respectively 2.551V, GND, 1,861V

TIP42C voltages with respect to GND (E,C,B) change from 5.05V, 9.33V, 16.78V without load to 5.05V, 0.41V, 16.78V when load is appied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fritzing can produce schematic diagrams instead of wiring diagrams.  Schematic diagrams are more useful than wiring diagrams when trying to undestand the function of a circuit.

Comment: Besides, a TIP42 looks nothing like that and the pins are in a different order.

Comment: Right away, if you're connecting your supply voltage directly to the base of a transistor you're probably doing something wrong. None of this looks like what I would expect to see for a cutoff circuit. Trying to work out a schematic but none of it makes sense. Where did you get the circuit from? Post a schematic as JRE requested please.

Comment: @JRE yes you are right, but I'm not able to build a decent circuit with it. Sorry. I've uploaded a drawing of the circuit (handmade)

Comment: @Finbarr the transistor is a TIP42C and from datasheet the order is BCE (ECB if upside down)

Comment: @GodJihyo thanks for the precious hint. I've seen a similar circuit on a forum where the idea was to create a cutoff circuit for a 12V battery. I've just modified the voltage divider resistors in order to adjust the cutoff voltage to the one of interest

Comment: @TheInterestedOne I don't see how that circuit will do anything, for a PNP transistor to turn on the base has to be  0.7 V lower than the emitter, if the base is tied to the positive  rail there's no way it can be lower than any other voltage in the circuit. I've got some cutoff circuit designs, I'll try to post one but I'm going to be offline for a few hours at least.

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks a lot for the reply! From what you say it is impossible for the circuit to work, maybe I've put the PNP reversed (ECB instead of BCE)? One of the things that I don't understand is why the circuit "works as expected" without load. Thanks in advance for your time and for the circuit design, whenever you'll have the right slot for it

Comment: @TheInterestedOne PNP the wrong way around might be the problem. Try it the other way around.

Comment: @GodJihyo ops... that's was the problem. Now the circuit is working as expected. Thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 1):

The bipolar transistor must me reversed (BCE instead of ECB).
The circuit is working properly

Thanks to all for the help!